# Returning array or results or array to main function C

Tags: c

Hi i have a little function that deletes the word from sentence, which starts with 2 consonants. There is the function:

```
char * fun_zod(char * sak)
{
    char * sep = " "; //Zodziu atskirejas - tarpas
    char * zodis = strtok(sak,sep); //Nurodome kad sakini suskirstytume i zodzius po viena
    char * zodmas[20];
    int i = 0;
    zodmas[0] = zodis;   //Iraso atskirai kiekviena zodi i masyva
    while (zodis != NULL)
    {
        if (zodis == NULL)
        break;
        i++;
        zodis = strtok(NULL,sep);
        zodmas[i] = zodis;
    }
    int n=i;
    for(int j = 0;j < n;j++)
    {
       if (!( zodmas[j][0] == 'a' || zodmas[j][0] == 'e' || zodmas[j][0] == 'i' || zodmas[j][0] == 'o' || zodmas[j][0] == 'u' ) && !( zodmas[j][1] == 'a' || zodmas[j][1] == 'e' || zodmas[j][1] == 'i' || zodmas[j][1] == 'o' || zodmas[j][1] == 'u' ))
       {
           zodmas[j]="";
       }

    }
    for (i=0;i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", zodmas[i]);
    }
}
```

Now i want to return the result to main function, to print the result not from function, but from main function. I know that in C i cant return array from function. Maybe someone can suggest me how to return results to main function? Thanks for help

Comment: you want to sent zodmas[] to main?

Comment: If it would be possible it would be perfect

Comment: Consider writing comments and variable names in English. We have no clue what they mean and that makes it difficult to read your code. Also consider fixing indentation.

Comment: And as to returning arrays, you can easily return a buffer allocated via `malloc`. Read about `malloc`. Another option would be to pass the address of a buffer from the caller, and write to it. In that case, also take care that you don't write past the end of the buffer. i.e. additionally pass the length of the buffer from the caller so that the function knows how long it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass zodmas and n as parameters.

Add a test to not overflow zodmas

```
char * fun_zod(char * sak, int *n, char **zodmas)                              
{                                                                              
    char * sep = " "; //Zodziu atskirejas - tarpas                             
    char * zodis = strtok(sak,sep); //Nurodome kad sakini suskirstytume i zodzius po viena 
    int i = 0;                                                                 
    zodmas[0] = zodis;   //Iraso atskirai kiekviena zodi i masyva              
    while (zodis != NULL && i < *n)                                            
    {                                                                          
        if (zodis == NULL)                                                     
            break;                                                             
        i++;                                                                   
        zodis = strtok(NULL,sep);                                              
        zodmas[i] = zodis;                                                     
    }                                                                          
    *n=i;                                                                      
    for(int j = 0;j < i;j++)                                                   
    {                                                                          
        if (!( zodmas[j][0] == 'a' || zodmas[j][0] == 'e' || zodmas[j][0] == 'i' || zodmas[j][0] == 'o' || zodmas[j][0] == 'u' ) && !( zodmas[j][1] == 'a' || zodmas[j][1] == 'e' || zodmas[j][1] == 'i' || zodmas[j][1] == 'o' || zodmas[j][1] == 'u' )) 
        {                                                                      
            zodmas[j]="";                                                      
        }                                                                      

    }                                                                          
}                                                                              
int main(void) {                                                               
    int n = 20;                                                                
    char *zodmas[20];                                                          
    fun_zod(strdup("toto tutu tata"), &n, zodmas);                             
    for (int i=0;i < n; i++)                                                   
    {                                                                          
        printf("%s ", zodmas[i]);                                              
    }                                                                          
    return 0;                                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Returning an array

### in a struct

I don't recommend doing so, but you can pack an array into a struct and return that struct:

```c
struct a {
  char *x[30];
};

struct a foo()
{
  struct a b = {};
  return b;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct a f;
  f = foo();
  return 0;
}
```

### returning a pointer

You can return a pointer to the start of the array

```c
char **
foo()
{
  char **array;
  array = calloc(30, sizeof *array);
  return array;
}
```

The length of the array can be communicated in various ways:

1. fixed length, as in the example above.
2. zero terminated: make sure that just the last element in the array is `NULL`, the calling function can determine the length of the array by checking for `NULL`.
3. the length may be returned via another variable:

   ```c
   char **
   foo (int *n)
   {
     char **array;
     *n = random_length_of_the_array
     array = calloc(30, sizeof *array);
     return array;
   }

   int
   main (int argc, char * argv[])
   {
     char **a;
     int length;
     a = foo (&length);
     ...
     free (a);
     ...
   ```

## Array provided by the calling function

You can lay the responsibility to allocate the array in the hands of the calling function. For example `strncpy` and `memcpy` work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array pointer to memory that has been dynamically allocated, but the caller is responsible for freeing that memory. I have used an array of string pointers, which can be any length (subject to memory). The number of elments is known because I have used a `NULL` end marker. So there is always at least one pointer in the array - an empty list is just one element value `NULL`. I could have used a linked list to do the job - perhaps more elegantly - but the question asked **how you can return an array from a function?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isvowel(int ch)
{
    char *vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
    return (strchr(vowels, ch) != NULL);
}

void free_zod(char **zod)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (zod[i] != NULL)
        free (zod[i++]);
    free (zod);
}

char **fun_zod(char * sak)
{
    char *sep = " \r\n\t";          // weed out tabs and newlines too
    char *zodis;
    char **zodmas = NULL;
    int i = 0, len;

    zodmas = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    zodmas[0] = NULL;               // end marker

    zodis = strtok(sak,sep);
    while (zodis != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(zodis);
        if (!isvowel(zodis[0]) && !isvowel(zodis[1]) && strlen(zodis)>=2)
        {
            zodis = "";
            len = 0;
        }
        zodmas = realloc(zodmas, (i+2) * sizeof(char*));
        zodmas[i] = malloc(len+1);  // string space
        strcpy(zodmas[i], zodis);
        zodmas[++i] = NULL;         // end marker
        zodis = strtok(NULL,sep);   // next token
    }
    return zodmas;
}

int main (void)
{
    char **zod;
    char input[201];
    int i = 0;

    if (fgets(input, 200, stdin) == NULL)
        return 0;
    zod = fun_zod(input);           // get array pointer

    while (zod[i] != NULL)          // NULL is ends marker
        printf("%s\n", zod[i++]);
    free_zod(zod);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve
one


four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass an array from main() function to fun_zod() function and use it.
Don't take array in fun_zod, then in that case array will be cleared coz of temporary variable concept.

Example:

```
void func(int *a)
{

    /* use this array here , and u dont need to send it back, it will be updated in main func also. */

    /* change array value here */

    a[0] = 7;

}

void main()
{

    int arr[10];

    func(arr);

    /* change will reflect here*/

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  #define MAXLINES 1000 //global

  main()
    {
        char *lineptr[MAXLINES]; /*pointers to lines*/

        //....//
        for(i=0; i< nlines; i++)
        printf("%s\n", lineptr[i] );    

    }



        int fun_zod(char * sak , char *lineptr[])
        {

        int len, nlines=0; // String lenght and number of lines
        char *p;

        char * sep = " "; //Zodziu atskirejas - tarpas
        char * zodis = strtok(sak,sep); //Nurodome kad sakini suskirstytume i zodzius po viena
        char * zodmas[20];
        int i = 0;
        zodmas[0] = zodis;   //Iraso atskirai kiekviena zodi i masyva
        while (zodis != NULL)
            {
            if (zodis == NULL)
            break;
            i++;
            zodis = strtok(NULL,sep);
            zodmas[i] = zodis;
            }
        int n=i;
            for(int j = 0;j < n;j++)
              {
               if (!( zodmas[j][0] == 'a' || zodmas[j][0] == 'e' || zodmas[j][0] == 'i' || zodmas[j][0] == 'o' || zodmas[j][0] == 'u' ) && !( zodmas[j][1] == 'a' || zodmas[j][1] == 'e' || zodmas[j][1] == 'i' || zodmas[j][1] == 'o' || zodmas[j][1] == 'u' ))
               {
                   zodmas[j]="";
               }
            }

        for (i=0;i < n; i++)
        {
            len = strlen(&zodmas[i]);
            p= malloc(sizeof (char *) * len);
            strcpy(p, &line[i]);
            lineptr[nlines++] = p;
        }
        return nlines;

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.